# How to convert number to GUID at JS

Tags: javascript, uuid, guid

Tell me how to convert a number to GUID?
We use GUID on the backend, I know that it is an encoded number, because the guys from the back showed me this code (below)
In some logic, I have to give them my number encoded in GUID, but I don't understand how to do it in JS, tell me, please.

Thaths back code:
var guid = Guid.Parse("00001620-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
BitConverter.ToInt64(guid.ToByteArray()).Dump();
result:  5664

Comment: Your guys from the backend are wrong in this particular case. GUID is not really a number, it is 128 bit value (by the way conversion to Int64, which is 64 bit value will fail with overflow at some point).
Simply put - don't do this, and tell them not to, as well

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to convert to a GUID.
Just make sure you send a string that looks like a GUID and parse/cast it in the backend.